# Quicksort 3 way partition code is not doing what it's told

Tags: java, algorithm, quicksort, partitioning

I need to make a quicksort method that utilizes 3 way partitioning. The algorithm I'm using can be found here https://algs4.cs.princeton.edu/lectures/23DemoPartitioning.pdf scroll down to the Dijkstra 3-way partitioning demo. For some arrays such as, 5 5 7 3 5 1 6 2 4 8, my method works. However when I put an array such as, 5 5 7 3 5 1 6 2 4 8 9 8, my code does not work properly. I get the output: 1 2 3 4 5 5 5 6 7 8 9 8. I know what the problem is, but I don't understand why my code isn't handling it. Here is my code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class QuickSortDriver {

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("\n\nEnter array elements: ");
        String s = scan.nextLine();
        String[] token = s.split(" ");
        int[] array = new int[token.length];

        for(int i=0; i < array.length; i++)
            array[i] = Integer.parseInt(token[i]);

        quicksort(array, 0, array.length - 1);

        System.out.print("\nSorted array: ");

        for(int i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
            System.out.printf("%d ", array[i]);

        System.out.print("\n\n");
        scan.close();
    }

    public static void quicksort(int [] array, int low, int high)
    {
        //debugging: shows what the array is
        //before the while loop
        System.out.print("\n");
        for(int j = low; j <= high; j++)
            System.out.printf("%d ", array[j]);

        if(high <= low) 
            return;

        int lt = low;
        int gt = high;
        int i = low;

        while(i <= gt)
        {
            if(array[i] < array[low])
                swap(array, lt++, i++);
            else if(array[i] > array[low])
                swap(array, i, gt--);
            else
                i++;
        }

        //debugging: shows what the array is
        //after the while loop
        System.out.print("\n");
        for(int j = low; j <= high; j++)
            System.out.printf("%d ", array[j]);

        quicksort(array, low, lt -1);
        quicksort(array, gt + 1, high);
    }

    public static void swap(int array[], int i, int j)
    {
        int tmp = array[i];
        array[i] = array[j];
        array[j] = tmp;
    }

}
```

I put the for loops that print out the array at the beginning and end of the sorting method for debugging purposes and by doing that I found the problem. Here is my input output with the debugging statements printed:

```
Enter array elements: 5 5 7 3 5 1 6 2 4 8 9 8

5 5 7 3 5 1 6 2 4 8 9 8 
4 3 2 1 5 5 6 5 8 9 8 7 
4 3 2 1 
3 2 1 4 
3 2 1 
2 1 3 
2 1 
1 2 
1 



6 5 8 9 8 7 
5 6 9 8 7 8 
5 
9 8 7 8 
8 7 9 8 <--right here is the problem
8 7 
7 8 
7 


Sorted array: 1 2 3 4 5 5 5 6 7 8 9 8
```

When my program gets to the 9 8 7 8 part of the array, it should do this:

(Please follow along with the logic in the Dijkstra 3-way partitioning algorithm.)

```
9 8 7 8

i = 9 lt = 9 gt = 8(at end) increment i

9 8 7 8

i = 8 lt = 9 gt = 8(at end) swap i and lt and increment i

8 9 7 8

i = 7 lt = 9 gt = 8(at end) swap i and lt and increment i

8 7 9 8
```

i = 8(at end) lt = 9 gt = 8(at end) Now at this point it should swap i and lt and increment i. However, it doesn't and I have no idea why. The condition in my while loop is while(i <= gt), therefore it should keep iterating at that point because i and gt are at the same indices (refer to the code), but it doesn't. If anyone here can help me fix this bug it would be greatly appreciated I'm literally about to start pulling my hair out.

Comment: I'm sure it's doing *exactly* what it's told. More likely, you told it to do the wrong thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use `lt` instead of `low` within your while loop. It should look like this:

```
    while(i <= gt)
    {
        if(array[i] < array[lt])
            swap(array, lt++, i++);
        else if(array[i] > array[lt])
            swap(array, i, gt--);
        else
            i++;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

This is not a bug fix. Merely some help to identify the problem:

Add more debugging like this:

```
    System.out.println("Part 1: " + low + " to " + (lt-1));
    System.out.println("Part 2: " + (gt+1) + " to " + high);
    quicksort(array, low, lt -1);
    quicksort(array, gt + 1, high);
```

If the initial input array is 9, 8, 7, 8 the array will be 8, 7, 9, 8 after the first while iteration. The new output becomes

```
Part 1: 0 to 1
Part 2: 4 to 3
```

which means the first two items - 8, 7 - will be sorted in the next round. But after that nothing happens since 4>3, so 9, 8 will remain in the wrong order. It is clear that if (in this case) Part 2 was "2 to 3", it all would be ok.

Sadly, it is less clear how to fix that. In this case, the following would work but I suspect that's not how Quicksort should work, and it might not work in other cases:

```
    quicksort(array, low, lt -1);
    quicksort(array, lt, high);
```